# Append mutiple tables to one datatable in c#

Tags: c#

i have two datatables A and B (with the same schema and structure) i need to append both tables data to one table.
For example

```
 Table A :
   column1 column2
    1       aaa
    2       bbb   

 Table B :
  column1 column2
    3       ccc
    4       ddd  

   Result Table should be :
    column1 column2
     1       aaa
     2       bbb  
     3       ccc
     4       ddd
```

Please let me know how can i achieve this using c# code.

Comment: see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use DataTable Merge

```
            dt1.Merge(dt2);
```